# Howto escape a " character in an hyperlink

Tags: support, markdown, hyperlinks

Example:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="
```

when I use the above URL as a direct hyperlink inside stackoverflow then the `"` character is automatically removed when a user selects the hyperlink.

I probably need some kind of escaping - but I couldn't figure out how.

Note: `&quot;` doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%22
```

I ran a single double quote through PHP's `urlencode`, which encoded the, you guessed it, chararcters needed to be changed when using a URL.

Comment: @vokuhila I recommend accepting my answer, since this is really about using a better link syntax for "troublesome" link characters rather than going to all the effort of manually encoding..

Comment: @Jeff Trying to steal my answer eh? Just Kidding. Vok, you need to click the checkmark next to Jeffs answer (The answer below this one)

Comment: @George Funny how computers make you seem like you are talking to yourself. Skype does that too.

Comment: @George: I have deleted that confusing comment

Answer (score 3):

```
- [link style one][1]  
- [link style two](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=")
- <http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=">
- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="

[1]: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="
```

Should work OK in all non-naked (bare URL) link styles:

- [link style one](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=")
- [link style two](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=")
- 
- http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i="

Comment: I tried [1]. But it didn't work. (mmmhh - did I accidently use [1:] instead of [1]: ... ? And the 4th dotted "link style" was the one I tried initially - but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

[As of recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60211/auto-escape-url-when-entering-with-hyperlink-button-ctrll/82263#82263), when entering a link via the button (or Ctrl-L), these characters will automatically be escaped.